# In Gem. Makkos 9a, how can Abaye suggest that a person is unaware of the prohibition to kill?

Tags: talmud-gemara, murder, maseches-makos

[Gemara Makkos 9a](https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.9a.7?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) reports:

> א״ל אביי אומר מותר אנוס הוא
>
> Abaye said to him: One who says that it is permitted to kill the
> victim is a victim of circumstances beyond his control, as he was
> unaware of the prohibition.

How can Abaye suggest that a person is unaware of the prohibition to kill? Is it not known by everyone that it is prohibited to kill?

And in addition, killing is one of those sins for which one must give up one's life? see[here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%99%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%92_%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8)

Comment: Are there not borderline cases where it's not obvious? Anything from abortion to warfare

Comment: What about someone who grew up on a desert island?

Comment: Maybe he decided the person was a moser who he thought he was allowed to kill. Or he decided he was a rodef or whatever. But in really the person wasn’t any of those. So he thought it was permitted when it wasn’t

Comment: There is a clear case here (https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%91_%D7%90) where the murderer thought he was justified / right - עולא במיסקיה לארעא דישראל איתלוו ליה תרין בני חוזאי בהדיה קם חד שחטיה לחבריה אמר ליה לעולא יאות עבדי אמר ליה אין ופרע ליה בית השחיטה